# SwiftUI on WatchOS 10: how to hide page indicator?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I want Tab View to hide the page indicator as I have my own custom page indicator already.

```
TabView(selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(0...10, id:\.self) { index in
        Button("tap \(index)") {
            selection = Int.random(in: 0...10)
        }
    }
}
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

This works fine on watchOS 8 and 9. But WatchOS 10 does not work as intended.

- When the view first appear, the indicator show.
- When scroll with finger, it does hide the indicator.
- But when jump to some pages by tap the button, the indicator shows again.

I'm using Xcode 15.0, testing on watchOS simulator 10.0

I want this to completely hide the page indicator.